# New tower system

Tags: desktop, pc

my old system is now more then 7 years old and has, with some updates over time, this components:

```
Motherboard Name: Asus P8P67 (3xPCI, 2xPCI-E x1, 2xPCI-E x16, 4xDDR3 DIMM, Audio, Gigabit LAN, IEEE-1394)
Motherboard Chipset: Intel Cougar Point P67, Intel Sandy Bridge  
CPU: Quad-core Intel Core i7-2600K, 4400 MHz (43 x 102)  
RAM: 16GB (4x4GB DDR3-1600 SDRAM)
DIMM1: G Skill ECO F3-12800CL8-4GBECO -- 4GB DDR3-1600 SDRAM (9-9-9-28 @ 800 MHz) (8-8-8-25 @ 711 MHz) (7-7-7-22 @ 622 MHz)
DIMM2: G Skill Ares F3-1600C9-4GAB -- 4GB DDR3-1600 SDRAM (11-11-11-28 @ 800 MHz) (10-10-10-27 @ 761 MHz) (9-9-9-24 @ 685 MHz) (8-8-8-22 @ 609 MHz) (7-7-7-19 @ 533 MHz) (6-6-6-16 @ 457 MHz)
DIMM3: G Skill ECO F3-12800CL8-4GBECO -- 4GB DDR3-1600 SDRAM (9-9-9-28 @ 800 MHz) (8-8-8-25 @ 711 MHz) (7-7-7-22 @ 622 MHz)
DIMM4: G Skill Ares F3-1600C9-4GAB -- 4GB DDR3-1600 SDRAM (11-11-11-28 @ 800 MHz) (10-10-10-27 @ 761 MHz) (9-9-9-24 @ 685 MHz) (8-8-8-22 @ 609 MHz) (7-7-7-19 @ 533 MHz) (6-6-6-16 @ 457 MHz)
Graphics card: EVGA - NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980 Ti  
Power supply: be quiet - Dark Power Pro (80 Plus Gold) - Model: BQT P9-550W  
case: AeroCool RS-9 Professional
```

My work is in the field of software development with also rendering videos and 3D animations. Unfortunately, my own system lacks in power, so on big projects I outsource the rendering part.
But I thought to myself, that after 7 years I can afford a new system with more power, that maybe also can hold 7 years or more (of course depending on the hardware progress).

By problem: I am not good in hardware knowledge.
I barley know the main things so I sat down, read some articles and came up with this first attempt of a new computer:
https://de.pcpartpicker.com/list/Gp2W7h

My Questions:

1. I am not sure with the storage. I am planning to use a SSD M2 with a RAID0 including two Western Digital 2TB. Is this something that should be used in a client desktop PC? Or should I use a SSD with a normal SSHD?
2. Should I additionally use a Intel Optane? Or is the new M2 something similar?
3. And Should I use two GTX 980 Ti in SLI, or one single GTX 1080 (normal, no Ti)
4. Is the cooling system I thought of enough for this computer? I am not a big fan of water cooling, but maybe it is necessary? I hope not, but I am willing to learn...
5. What do you think in general of the system?
6. Where do you think is the problem zone in this system? So what part is the weakest and pulls down the rest?

Sorry for my bad hardware knowledge. I hope, you understand, that not everybody must be an expert in everything. I have my strong points in other areas ;)
Also thanks for any help.

Comment: You don't get to delete and re-ask your question because it got closed. Fix your existing question instead.